# Fire window.open from alert popup

Tags: javascript

I have an ajax command where on return I need to call `window.open(url, '_blank')`, and I run into cases were the browser blocks this call (returns null) which makes sense.

I understand I need a user action for that, and I'm ok with showing a modal 'Open in New tab' etc with an 'OK' button that will then do the `window.open`, however `alert()` does not have an `onclick` handler and so if I understand correctly will not work here.

What are my options ? do I have to code or bring a third party popup with an `onclick` to do this ? (any recommendations for one?)

Comment: You can’t use alert for this, but you can make your own custom alert box where you can add this functionality. It’s even possible to override the regular alert function (by assigning a new function to window.alert, though overriding native functions may be dangerous).

Comment: Create a custom popup window with a message and button. You can put a custom onClick handler on it then. See example here: https://codepen.io/OneCent/pen/OJJereB

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
let openNewTab = function(){
  if(confirm("Open new tab?"))
  {
    window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank');
  }
}
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/jeff-tian/pen/bGGPzrX

Comment: The thing is even just directly calling window.open works sometime in some browsers .. bit of hit and miss .. do you know if your code constitutes 'user action'?

Comment: This solution doesn't work in Chrome at my side. However, you can click the codepen link to check it if it works on your side.

Comment: @JeffTian Weird, because I was testing this in console on Chrome 78.0.3904.108

Comment: I tested on macOS, with Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Since the code was being executed in the context of your console, chrome allowed the window to open. But browsers are less forgiving when it's 3rd party script.

Answer (score 0):

Seems true. If you don't want to code a popup then you can use `ant-design` or `Taro`.

The `Taro` example here: https://pa-ca.me/pages/cards/cards

[image]

Code is here: https://github.com/Jeff-Tian/me/blob/654f7b144bf7fa82fc68e28320c51856d5f9b815/src/components/cards/index.tsx#L46

Basically try `window.open` first, then check error, if error then popup:

```
const url = ajax('url')
try {
  window.open(url)
}catch(ex){
  showPopup({onConfirm: ()=>window.open(url)})
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot of imports/dependencie for an alert